# Access Denied when running invoke-command in a saved script on local machine

Tags: powershell, scripting, access-denied, invoke-command

I am trying to create a script that targets all the servers in one of my SCCM device collections and remotely restarts a few services and runs a couple of SCCM client actions.

I discovered that the invoke-command is failing to run on my localhost due to an access denied error. However, this command works without issue on a normal PowerShell window. I have also tried running the script against my domain controller and it also works, so the issue is with running it on the localhost.
[Screenshot of lab and script failures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4a8cT.png)

You can see in the PowerShell window, I am currently running the script on a server called DP01. The invoke-command sent in that window runs without trouble. In the PowerShell ISE window, you can see that it receives access denied on DP01, but it is a success on my domain controller DC01.

No matter where the script is saved the error is the same, I have full administrator (Domain Admins) rights to the server and the folders have sufficient access. I am not sure what the problem here is.

Comment: You're running one as admin, and the other you're not?

Comment: I found that out shortly after posting the question. So why does running the script in non-admin allow me to execute on remote computers?

Comment: I really don't understand what you're looking at. What I'm looking at, is your getting successful results from querying dc and not dp

Answer (score 0):

Running PowerShell ISE in administrator mode first then opening the scripts solved the issue.